# Change <p> to <table>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wants to change the output of the `<p id="demo>` to `<table>` with `<tr>` and `<td>`but it involved Javascript in the output so it doesn't on what I've tried.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Predict</button>
<div id="demo" align="center"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedprg = '';
  var selectedcount = '';
  var selectedcity = '';
  var average = '';
 function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">Selected program</td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">${selectedprg}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">Total number of students</td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">${selectedcount}</td>
  </tr>
</table>'

  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#prg").change( function(){
      selectedprg = $('#prg option:selected').text(); 
      selectedcount = $('#prg option:selected').data('prgcount');
selectedcity = $('#prg option:selected').data('citycount');
      if(selectedcount > 5){
        average = selectedcount / 3 + 5;
      } else{
        average = selectedcount / 3 - 5;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Current output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Could someone assist on this? Thank you.

Comment: You can create elements using jquery, `$('<table></table>')`, so in your code you can set the innerHTML equal to a jquery element,  `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $('<table></table>')`

Comment: Hi @bryansteven314 - Thank you for your reply. So I needs to do something alike document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = $('<table><tr><td>Selected program</td></tr></table>') All the table data need to put it here ?

Comment: How about <p id="demo"></p> ? Do I need to replace it with anything? I think will be more easier if you show me the code flow.... @bryansteven314

Comment: Exactly, I would change the p tag to a div

Comment: If you wanted to get fancy I would recommend looking into templating, specifically handlebars but what I've suggested should suffice

Comment: I've tried as the edited code but there is no output, please assist @bryansteven314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">Selected program</td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">${selectedprg}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">Total number of students</td>
    <td style="padding: 5px;">${selectedcount}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
`
```

the styling should be writing with css ofcourse.

Comment: Hi @Barak Avraham - Thank you for your reply. I've tried as the edited code but there is no output, please assist....

Comment: @ravinc You didn't copy the code correctly, you added " " which breaks the code.

Comment: Yes, just noticed and changed already...but still no output @Barak Avraham

Comment: @ravinc You still didn't copy the code correctly, you have ' in the end instead of `, If you still getting errors after this please add the errors to your comment.

Comment: ravin you have mismatched string quotes, one is ` and another is ', change them both to ` ` and that will fix your problem

Comment: Ohh I'm really sorry, guys. Ok this works perfect now. Thank you so much bryan and barak. You saved my life! Haha... Have a nice day